# dynamodb how to query by sort key only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have written some python code, I want to query dynamoDB data by sort key.
I remember I can use follow-up code successful:

```
 table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('event_status').eq(event_status))
```

My table structure column

```
primary key:event_id
sort key: event_status
```

Comment: I believe this can be done by creating a `Global Secondary Index` in the form of an `Inverted Index`.

Answer (score 37):

You have to create a global secondary index (GSI) for the sort key in order to query on it alone.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to scan (and maybe you shouldn't), you will need to create a [GSI (Global Secondary Index)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) for that, and set `event_status` as the GSIPK.

so your table config will be:

```
 table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName="your_table",
        KeySchema=[
            {"AttributeName": "event_id", "KeyType": "HASH"},  # Partition key
            {"AttributeName": "event_status", "KeyType": "RANGE"},  # Sort key
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {"AttributeName": "event_id, "AttributeType": "S"},
            {"AttributeName": "event_status", "AttributeType": "S"},
            {"AttributeName": "gsi_event_status", "AttributeType": "S"},
            {"AttributeName": "gsi_event_id", "AttributeType": "S"},
        ],
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
            {
                "IndexName": "gsiIndex",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {"AttributeName": "gsi_event_status", "KeyType": "HASH"},
                    {"AttributeName": "gsi_event_id", "KeyType": "RANGE"},
                ],
                "Projection": {"ProjectionType": "ALL"},
            },
        ],
        BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST",
    )
```

Be mindful that GSIs can be expensive and you might wanna change the [ProjectionType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Projection.html) if you don't need all attributes.

Now you can query by pk:

```
table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('event_id').eq(event_id))
```

or by the GSI PK which is set to your sk:

```
lookup.query(
        IndexName="gsiIndex",
        KeyConditionExpression=Key("gsi_event_status").eq(event_status),
    )
```

Comment: The event_id and event_status are listed twice in the AttributeDefinitions. Is there a reason for that or doesn't it work the same with the duplicate entries removed?

Comment: I think it was meant to define attributes for main table and GSI, will update with different names so it's more obvious

Answer (score 9):

The scan API should be used if you would like to get data from DynamoDB without using Hash Key attribute value.

**Example:-**

```
fe = Attr('event_status').eq("new");

response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=fe        
    )

for i in response['Items']:

print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(        
        FilterExpression=fe,        
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
        )

    for i in response['Items']:
        print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

Comment: Note that scanning is not the same as querying.  You will be iterating over all the values so it is much less efficient than a query.  If you really need to efficiently query on ``event_status`` you should consider creating a GSI for that field.

Answer (score 1):

According to the main concept of the sort key, it is part of main cluster in the partition key to define some filter expression with partition key in query. so there is no ability to search on the sort key alone and without partition key. unless to define a global secondary index on the sort key.

Answer (score 0):

### By using FilterExpression we can scan the table using Sort key

**NOTE:** here **LastUpdated** is sortkey

Example:

```
from_date = "fromdate"
to_date = "todate"

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-south-1')
table = dynamodb.Table("your-tablename")
response =table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('LastUpdated').between(from_date,to_date))
    )
result = response['Items']
```

Comment: Be careful, this only filters up to 1MB of data that is returned from the original query. From the docs: "A filter expression is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned"